# conversion of date into seconds in unix

Tags: shell-script, osx, date

I have a requirement where I will be give the time in below format

`2019-02-08T19:24:30.220Z` by this I need to output number of days between the given date and present date.

given date = `2019-02-08T19:24:30.220Z`
present date = `2019-02-20T19:24:30.220Z`

output = `12`

Comment: What _unix_ is it? Does that _unix_ have GNU utilities, ksh93, zsh, perl or python?

Comment: Your clock must be off as you posted your question at 2019-02-20T11:03:04Z

Comment: I am using Mac and shell is zsh

Comment: I've added a zsh solution to my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `ksh93` (often installed by default on commercial SysV based unices like AIX or Solaris), which also happens to be the `/bin/sh` of Solaris 11 and newer:

```
date=2019-02-08T19:24:30.220Z
export LC_ALL=C # to make sure the decimal radix is "."
then_in_seconds=$(printf '%(%s.%N)T\n' "$date")
now_in_seconds=$(printf '%(%s.%N)T\n' now)
difference_in_seconds=$((now_in_seconds - then_in_seconds))
difference_in_24h_periods=$((difference_in_seconds / 24 / 60 / 60))
echo "Result: $difference_in_24h_periods"
```

At 2019-02-20T11:17:30Z and a bit, that gave me:

```
Result: 11.6618110817684377
```

You can use `$((f(difference_in_24h_periods)))` where `f` is one of `round`, `floor`, `ceil`, `nearbyint`, `trunc`, `rint`, `int` like in C if you want the difference as an integer, or use `printf` format specifications to specify the number of significant digits.

With `zsh`:

```
zmodload zsh/datetime
date=2019-02-08T19:24:30.220Z
TZ=UTC0 strftime -rs then_in_seconds '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S' "${date%.*}"
then_in_seconds+=.${${date##*.}%Z}
now_in_seconds=$EPOCHREALTIME
difference_in_seconds=$((now_in_seconds - then_in_seconds))
difference_in_24h_periods=$((difference_in_seconds / 24 / 60 / 60))
echo "Result: $difference_in_24h_periods"
```